# Bash - Print a variable in single quotes, but the default value without quotes

Tags: bash

My requirement is to print a variable in single quotes if the variable has some value; however if not then print the default value without quotes.

My attempts:

`var='hello'
echo "'${var}'" || echo NULL`

Output:
`'hello'`

`var=''
echo "'${var}'" || echo NULL`

Output:
`''`

I want result similar to:
`echo ${var:-NULL}`

Output:
`NULL`

Comment: What's the context for wanting to generate output with literal quotes even when they aren't called for? The answer by @oguzismail, using `"${var@Q]}"`, will (for the very recent versions of bash that support it) quote the contents of your variable *in whatever manner is needed to generate a valid shell-escaped version of your string*. `hello` doesn't need any quotes to be shell-escaped, but if you had, say, `var='hello world'`, it would expand to some kind of correct quoting -- be it `hello\ world` or `'hello world'` or `hello' 'world`.

Comment: ...just adding literal single quotes at the beginning and end of a string isn't safe if you're using that string in a context where it's parsed by a shell. Think about `var=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` -- even if you add fixed/literal single quotes around it, you'll be **unquoting** the second substring, and thus making it execute.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ "$var" ]; then
    echo "${var@Q}"
else
    echo NULL
fi
```

Note that `"${var@Q}"` expands to a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input. If what you want is just quotes use `"'$var'"`.

Comment: This works, but using `foo && bar || baz` as if it were `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi` is fragile: If `foo` succeeds but `bar` fails, then you can have `baz` run despite `foo`'s success.

Comment: (...well, works if the OP wants correct shell quoting, vs just wanting literal single quotes; it might be necessary to explain the difference for them to understand why/how it's correct -- also a good idea to mention the version dependency so they don't try to run it on bash 3.2 or 4.0 and decide it "doesn't work").

Answer (score 2):

*POSIX* shell code, no `if`s:

```
var=hello; echo ${var:+\'}"${var:-NULL}"${var:+\'}
var='';    echo ${var:+\'}"${var:-NULL}"${var:+\'}
```

Output:

```
'hello'
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this oneliner.